# How to select all elements whose parent is same

Tags: sql-server

I am working on sql query. i have a table:

```
Category(Category_ID,Category_Name,Parent_ID)
```

I want to select all `Category_ID` from Category table whose `Parent_ID` is 6 and also its Parent `Category_ID`.

I have used following sql query:

```
select * from Category where Parent=6 and Category_ID=6
```

but it is not working.Plaese help me

Comment: Field name,where (Parent or Parent_ID)?

Comment: Did you mean "or"? select * from Category where Parent=6 or Category_ID=6

Comment: I think you input the wrong field name "Parent", it's "Parent_ID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Category c
WHERE c.Parent_ID = 6 
OR    c.Category_ID=6
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Parent_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
         Category_Name ASC
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c79e7/3/0)</kbd>

This will select all children with parent-id=6 and also the parent-record itself.